# How can I create a dir but remove it if it already exists in Perl?

Tags: perl, create-directory

I would like to create a dir, but if it already exists I would like to remove it (along with all its content) first.

Should I explicitly add an `if (-d ...)` or is there a simpler `mkdir` that already does that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use functions from the core [File::Path](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) module:

```
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);

remove_tree('foo/bar/baz');
make_path('foo/bar/baz');
```

Comment: It's quite annoying that I can't use `remove_tree($path) or die "...", but have to explicitly add a variable to capture an error and then check it.